# Запуск скрипта в будни в определённое время

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, datetime

У меня есть скрипт, который должен запускаться только по будням в определённое время. Как запретить скрипту запускаться в выходные?

Comment: Составить правильное расписание в планировщике. Можно дополнительно сделать проверку в скрипте при старте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы узнать день недели:

```
    from datetime import date
    import calendar

    my_date = date.today()
    calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()]
```

Дальше делаете проверку на день и запускаете скрипт